# Unable to find an entry point named EnumerateSecurityPackagesW in DLL security.dll

Tags: .net, ssl, webclient

I'm trying to download a file with WebClient class via SSL.

new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://file")

But I'm getting this ugly exception:
Unable to find an entry point named EnumerateSecurityPackagesW in DLL security.dll.

Google search said that I would have a security.dll in my bin folder. But I don't!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What have you called your assemblies? It sounds like something is getting in the way of loading the standard Windows security.dll, which .NET wants to use. If your assembly, or any assembly in your directory is called security.dll that will get loaded first, and then everything falls apart.

If that's not the case there may be one in your path, try `dir /s security.dll` from the root of all your drives to see if there are other DLLs named badly ...

Comment: Hmm, strange. I'd turn on binding logging then and see if that points to anything - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx security.dll is a windows system file, it should not be in your bin folder at all.

Comment: What Operating System are you running on? What version of the .NET framework?